# Scrabble Word Finder and point counter function not computing?

Tags: python, list

Here is what I'm supposed to do:

Scrabble Word Finder: Your user will enter the tiles which they currently have.  Your program will print all words in the dictionary which can be created by those tiles.  Then, it will print the word with the most scrabble points and the point total.

Here is my code thus far:

```
def main():
    scrabblefinder()

def scrabbleFinder():
    value_list = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2,
                  'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 
                  'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 
                  'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}
    string1=str(input("What tiles do you have?: "))
    ls1 = list(string1)
    string2 = open("scrabble_wordlist_finder.txt","r")
    highest = 0
    higheststring = ""
    points = 0
   for line in string2:
   ls2=list(line)
  if len(string1)+1>=len(line):
     #ls2.sort()
     x=0
     for n in ls2:
         if n >= ls1[x+1]:

                x+=1
         else:
             break
     if x+1>=len(ls2):
         line=line.strip();
         word_index = 0
         total = 0
         points = sum(value_list[char] for char in line)
         if points > highest:
             highest = points
             higheststring = line
         print(str(line),",",points,"points")
 print("The highest scoring word is:",higheststring,",",points,"points.")
 main()
```

However, if I enter the tiles, for example, "qwertyas", it will print the following:

```
we , 5 points
wert , 7 points
west , 7 points
wet , 6 points
why , 12 points
wiry , 10 points
wis , 6 points
wist , 7 points
wit , 6 points
witty , 11 points
wiz , 15 points
wo , 5 points
wort , 7 points
wos , 6 points
wost , 7 points
wot , 6 points
wow , 9 points
wry , 9 points
xi , 9 points
xis , 10 points
xu , 9 points
xyst , 14 points
ye , 5 points
yes , 6 points
yet , 6 points
yett , 7 points
yew , 9 points
you , 6 points
yow , 9 points
yurt , 7 points
zest , 13 points
zesty , 17 points
The highest scoring word is: zesty , 17 points.
```

Why is it printing tiles that I didn't even enter? Also, why isn't it removing tiles so they can't be used again?

Comment: There are so many errors in your code that you really have to think again and look more carefully. One hint: z will need to be reset to zero for every word and you will need to break the inner loop when you've found a match. And instead of `y==x` (what?!), try `x in word`. There are yet more errors, though!

Answer (score 1):

You should include how you are calling the functions and the errors, but I can see some problems just from this code alone.  You never set `word` to anything in the `score_word_1` function.  `txt.close` should have parentheses so it actually calls the close function.

What is `y`?  You never set it to anything, but you're comparing it.

Answer (score 1):

`line.strip` should be `line.strip()`  You are assigning line to a function.

```
In [5]: s="abc "

In [6]: s=s.strip

In [7]: s
Out[7]: <function strip>
In [9]: s="abc "

In [10]: s=s.strip()

In [11]: s
Out[11]: 'abc'
```

You can use `with` to open your as it will automatically close the file and list comprehension to create your `myList`:

```
with open("scrabble_wordlist_finder.txt", "r") as f:
    myList = [line.strip() for line in f]

if y == x: # y has not been assigned a value anywhere
```